# How do I gift a book from the iBookstore?

Tags: books, itunes-store, gift

On the iTunes Store, you can gift people music, apps, etc. by clicking on the down arrow next to the buy button and choosing `Gift This ...`.

That option, however, is not available on books in the iBookstore:

[image]

How can I give someone a book from the iBookstore?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Updated 17 Dec 2013.

As [reported by Macworld](http://www.macworld.com/article/2081129/apple-adds-gifting-options-to-the-ibookstore.html), the iBookstore now allows you to gift books:

> Gifting in the iBookstore works identically to Apple’s iTunes and App Store counterparts: Just choose the book you’d like to gift, then tap either the dropdown arrow next to the price (on a Mac) or the Share button (on an iOS device).

More details are in their article, but by-and-large it seems to behave exactly as you would expect.

---

### My original answer:

You can’t; iBook gifting isn’t supported yet.

From [Apple’s iBooks FAQs page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4059):

> **Can I gift a book?**
>
> No, you cannot gift a book in the iBookstore at this time.

The phrase “at this time” suggests that it’s coming in the future, but Apple haven’t announced anything yet.

Comment: Seems like this no longer works, at least on iOS